# Non-existent tuples in a self-joined table

Tags: sql

I'm playing with an algorithm to 'solve' activity networks - it's for a course in Project Management. The algorithm works on paper, but in order to solve it with a computer, I need a clever query which finds non-existent tuples in a self-joined table.

Let's say that the activities are as follows:
A goes to B, A goes to C, B goes to D, C goes to D
The table (called 'CPM') which I am using is populated thus:

```
+----+----------+--------+---------+
| ID | Fromnode | Tonode | Counter |
+----+----------+--------+---------+
|  1 | A        | B      | 0       |  
+----+----------+--------+---------+
|  2 | A        | C      | 0       | 
+----+----------+--------+---------+
|  3 | B        | D      | 0       | 
+----+----------+--------+---------+
|  4 | C        | D      | 0       | 
+----+----------+--------+---------+
```

I am trying to write a query which return all the 'fromnodes' which don't have a corresponding 'tonodes'. This is what I wrote

```
select id, fromnode
from cpm
where counter = 0
and not exists (select 'X'
from cpm cpm1
where tonode = cmp1.fromnode)
```

but this is returning all four tuples, not just the first two.

Queries using 'not exists' are hard enough to understand as it is, and the self join only makes things worse. What should be the query? BTW, I'm using Firebird, but I don't think that that's the problem.

TIA, 
No'am

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try an outer join: `select a.id, a.fromnode from cpm as a left outer join cpm as b on a.fromnode = b.tonode  where b.fromnode is null`.

Comment: I don't know whether to accept your answer as it gave the wrong result, but at least indicated what the correct result was (or maybe I misled you). Your query returns 'D', not 'A'. Here is the correct query -

Comment: select a.id, a.fromnode
from cpm a
left outer join cpm b
on a.fromnode = b.tonode
where b.fromnode is null

Comment: @No'am: his idea was correct and he solved the problem (or showed you how to), I think he just went to fast in the query itself. Thanks for accepting.

Comment: oh i read the question wrongly (i did think you wanted the last two rows -- did not read the "not just the first two" properly). thanks for the correction. i guess i don't understand the phrase "don't have a corresponding tonodes".